# Best way to write slots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a simple combinatorial argument where I use slots __ __ __ to represent possible positions. Is there a latex command to draw these slots are a simple tikz command

Comment: Welcome! Could you please explain your question a bit more by providing more context? For slots you do not need any package, `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\underline{\hspace{2ex}}\hspace{1ex}\underline{\hspace{2ex}}
\end{document}` is sufficient, so users need more context to understand what you really wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely to me that you will want to print a variable number of slots. Expanding on Schrödinger's cat's comment, I'd define a `\slots` macro that can produce a specified number of slots, with three slots being the default. You can do this by wrapping Schrödinger's cat comment inside a `\foreach` loop from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). This way you can produce

[image]

using

```
\slots

\slots[4]

\slots[5]
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\slots[1][3]{\foreach \slot in {1,...,#1}{\underline{\hspace{1.5ex}}\,}}
\begin{document}

    \slots

    \slots[4]

    \slots[5]
\end{document}
```